# Chrome extension webRequest fired multiple times

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension in which I want to open a dialog box each time the page is partially (ajax) or fully reloaded.

In my background page I am catching the ajax request like this :

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if (details.frameId == 0) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
                "file": "/js/Dialog.js"
            });
        }
    },
    {urls: ["https://*/]"}
);
```

In my Dialog.js I am checking if the dialog box has already been initialized so I do not get multiple dialog boxes but it does not work, it does not seem to be working as I get 2 dialogs. This is what I do to check if it has been initialized :

```
if (!document.getElementById("my-dialog"))
```

Comment: See the documentation: add `types: ['xmlhttprequest']` to the filter parameter.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Events `onCompleted` fires for each resource was loaded on a tab (images, fonts, styles, etc).

You need to improve you event filtering, or use `chrome.tabs.onCreated`and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` together in order to catch tab's load finish.

And this: 
    !document.getElementById("my-dialog")
may not work, because DOM updating is slow operation, so when next event was fired, you DOM may be still not updated.

This simple trick shall work better:

```
var isLoaded = isLoaded || false; 
if(!isLoaded) {
    // ... load you dialog ...
    isLoaded = true; 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand how the trick can work because each time I will enter in Dialog.js, isLoaded will be reseted and I will enter again in the condition, i might be wrong ... I will try to find some informations on the two events you mentionned. Thanks.

Comment: It will not reset vars in the content script.